# Request header is returning NULL

Tags: java, servlets

I have some issue with the code below, `req.getHeader()` is returning `NULL`

```
// The code below returns the expected value
String header = req.getHeader("x-key");
String size = req.getHeader("x-size");
String contentType = req.getContentType();

logger.info("Content-Length: " + req.getContentLength());
logger.info("x-key : " + header);
logger.info("x-size : " + size);

// The value of req.getHeader below is returning NULL
for (Enumeration e = req.getHeaderNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
   String headerName = (String) e.nextElement();
   logger.info("Name = " + headerName + " " + "Value = " + req.getHeader(headerName ));
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks OK. If `getHeader()` returns `null` the header is indeed null, i.e. was not sent by client.

So, first check your client and be sure it sends the header. Second, try to use network sniffer, e.g. Wireshark and record the network activity.

If you need more assistance please post your client's code.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to get the same header from outside the loop and inside the loop, that i'm testing to get the header "x-key" from both code blocks

Comment: Check whether is is `null` value or string that contains 4 letters: `N-U-L-L`

Answer (score 0):

The below is part of the extract from the api docs.

public java.util.Enumeration getHeaderNames()

```
Some servlet containers do not allow servlets to access headers using this method, in which case this method returns null
```